# How to select all cells in a section except one cell in collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

**I want to select all the cells in the section in collectionView but except one cell that can't be selected.** I tried so many ways and searched a lot but no help. What I have now is only to select multiple cells in collectionView.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if deleteMode == true {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Delete", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(tryThisMethod))
        self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.toggleSelected()
        self.posiciones = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems!
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't modify states of a cell outside of `cellForItem`. Cells are reused and the changes don't persist. Maintain the `selected` state in the model and set the state of the cell in `cellForItem`. In `didSelectItemAt` modify the **model** and reload the view.

Comment: Could you show more the details? Are you `allowsMultipleSelection` always or just in the case?